# Unable to figure out reason behind exception rounding necessary

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate, exception

I am writing below code to convert the bigDecimal I am picking from db to bigInteger. However, I am getting an exception which can be seen below, along with the code. Can anyone please go through it and guide me thanks

```
IntegrationsUtils.logMessage(Level.INFO, "WT Refund | Processing Transaction: " + id);

BigInteger bigIntegerId = id.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).toBigInteger();

WTRefund wtRefundTransaction = getDaoFactory().getWtRefundDao()
.findById(id.toBigInteger());
```

For the above mentioned code I am getting following error, can anyone guide what is causing this ? Value of id here is 154 in db. Furthermore I have also tried 2nd line of code but it also gave same error. Any guidance would mean a lot.

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.commonNeedIncrement(BigDecimal.java:4717)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.needIncrement(BigDecimal.java:4767)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.divideAndRound(BigDecimal.java:4681)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.setScale(BigDecimal.java:2940)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.toBigIntegerExact(BigDecimal.java:3557)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.wrap(BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.wrap(BigIntegerTypeDescriptor.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DecimalTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(DecimalTypeDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.Loadable.hydrate(Loadable.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractRows(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4521)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:539)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2835)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2812)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2768)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2812)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3400)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3362)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy117.find(Unknown Source)
    at com.tlx.afx.integrations.commons.persistence.dao.BaseDAOPrimary.findById(BaseDAOPrimary.java:96)
    at com.tlx.afx.integrations.commons.persistence.dao.BaseDAOPrimary$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$486dd08b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.tlx.afx.integrations.commons.persistence.dao.WTRefundDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3538153.findById(<generated>)
    at com.tlx.afx.integrations.inbound.accountingentries.wtrefund.WTRefundService.listenForWTRefundTransactions(WTRefundService.java:65)
    at com.tlx.afx.integrations.inbound.accountingentries.AccountingEntriesJobsTrigger.listenForIncomingTransaction15(AccountingEntriesJobsTrigger.java:418)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
```

Update:

```
        BigInteger bigIntegerId = id.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).toBigInteger();

        WTRefund wtRefundTransaction = getDaoFactory().getWtRefundDao().findById(bigIntegerId);
```

The above code is still giving the same error. Id is not a decimal but whole number which is 154.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. The `bigIntegerId` variable isn't used.

Comment: It seems like `.toBigIntegerExact()` has been used somewhere (6th error line down) and it doesn't care for floating point values (like: 2134.5). Also...can you not just do `BigInteger bigIntegerId = id.toBigInteger();`?

Comment: Plus, why is an *id* being rounded *at all*?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because Hibernate is calling this method on the BigInteger class:

```
public BigInteger toBigIntegerExact() {
    // round to an integer, with Exception if decimal part non-0
    return this.setScale(0, ROUND_UNNECESSARY).inflated();
}
```

Note the comment about an Exception - that's what you're seeing. In essence the problem is that Hibernate is trying to convert a BigDecimal value to a BigInteger value, but the fractional part of the BigDecimal is non-zero, so it fails.

In short, it's trying to convert a decimal value with a fractional part (e.g. 1.2) to an exact integer value (i.e. without rounding), which can't be done.

WHy exactly Hibernate is trying to do this depends on the database table schema and the target class (WTRefund), which you haven't provided.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `id.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).toBigInteger()` on the `findById` method should solve the issue.

Or use in fact the `bigIntegerId` in the findById.

Comment: BigInteger bigIntegerId = id.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).toBigInteger();

                WTRefund wtRefundTransaction = getDaoFactory().getWtRefundDao().findById(bigIntegerId);


Still getting the same error

Comment: can you post the code for com.tlx.afx.integrations.commons.persistence.dao.BaseDAOPrimary?